# Loosing IPv4 and DHCP constantly asking for IP

Tags: networking, networkmanager, dhcp, ipv4, avahi

Using Ubuntu 16.04, almost every day I'm loosing IPv4 address, being dropped by Avahi Daemon.

Also, I see the DHCP is not "waiting" for leasing time to finish to request an address again, it does it every some minutes, but I cannot see a pattern.

Then, suddenly and without any previous error, Avahi Daemon withdraws the IP from interface eth0:

`Aug 11 11:55:14 jorgee avahi-daemon[2734]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.2.94 on eth0.`

This is the last part of the syslog.

```
Aug 11 11:43:11 jorgee systemd[1]: Started Automatically refresh installed snaps.
Aug 11 11:43:11 jorgee systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 4h 33min 5.892892s random time.
Aug 11 11:43:11 jorgee systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 48min 39.947211s random time.
Aug 11 11:43:13 jorgee dbus[2803]: [system] Reloaded configuration
Aug 11 11:44:04 jorgee dhclient[12492]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.94 on eth0 to 192.168.2.254 port 67 (xid=0x188018e6)
Aug 11 11:44:04 jorgee dhclient[12492]: DHCPACK of 192.168.2.94 from 192.168.2.254
Aug 11 11:44:04 jorgee root: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
Aug 11 11:44:05 jorgee dhclient[12492]: bound to 192.168.2.94 -- renewal in 800 seconds.
Aug 11 11:46:15 jorgee dhclient[12636]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.94 on eth0 to 192.168.2.254 port 67 (xid=0x51cc22fc)
Aug 11 11:46:15 jorgee dhclient[12636]: DHCPACK of 192.168.2.94 from 192.168.2.254
Aug 11 11:46:15 jorgee root: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
Aug 11 11:46:15 jorgee dhclient[12636]: bound to 192.168.2.94 -- renewal in 758 seconds.
Aug 11 11:47:33 jorgee dhclient[12712]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.94 on eth0 to 192.168.2.254 port 67 (xid=0x6788bfce)
Aug 11 11:47:33 jorgee dhclient[12712]: DHCPACK of 192.168.2.94 from 192.168.2.254
Aug 11 11:47:33 jorgee root: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
Aug 11 11:47:33 jorgee dhclient[12712]: bound to 192.168.2.94 -- renewal in 746 seconds.
Aug 11 11:49:08 jorgee systemd-timesyncd[12709]: Timed out waiting for reply from 192.168.2.254:123 (192.168.2.254).
Aug 11 11:52:42 jorgee dhclient[14855]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.94 on eth0 to 192.168.2.254 port 67 (xid=0x41dfce98)
Aug 11 11:52:42 jorgee dhclient[14855]: DHCPACK of 192.168.2.94 from 192.168.2.254
Aug 11 11:52:42 jorgee dhclient[14855]: bound to 192.168.2.94 -- renewal in 703 seconds.
Aug 11 11:54:16 jorgee dhclient[12677]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.94 on eth0 to 192.168.2.254 port 67 (xid=0x7456460e)
Aug 11 11:54:16 jorgee dhclient[12677]: DHCPACK of 192.168.2.94 from 192.168.2.254
Aug 11 11:54:16 jorgee root: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
Aug 11 11:54:17 jorgee dhclient[12677]: bound to 192.168.2.94 -- renewal in 770 seconds.
Aug 11 11:55:14 jorgee avahi-daemon[2734]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.2.94 on eth0.
Aug 11 11:55:14 jorgee avahi-daemon[2734]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.2.94.
Aug 11 11:55:14 jorgee avahi-daemon[2734]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 11 11:55:16 jorgee whoopsie[2731]: [11:55:16] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Aug 11 11:55:16 jorgee whoopsie[2731]: [11:55:16] offline
Aug 11 11:56:14 jorgee sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/jorgee is already mounted
Aug 11 11:56:34 jorgee dhclient[11554]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.94 on eth0 to 192.168.2.254 port 67 (xid=0x2894ec32)
Aug 11 11:56:34 jorgee dhclient[11554]: send_packet: Network is unreachable
Aug 11 11:56:34 jorgee dhclient[11554]: send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address.
Aug 11 11:56:34 jorgee dhclient[11554]: dhclient.c:2386: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
Aug 11 11:56:37 jorgee dhclient[11554]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.94 on eth0 to 192.168.2.254 port 67 (xid=0x2894ec32)
Aug 11 11:56:37 jorgee dhclient[11554]: send_packet: Network is unreachable
Aug 11 11:56:37 jorgee dhclient[11554]: send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address.
Aug 11 11:56:37 jorgee dhclient[11554]: dhclient.c:2386: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
Aug 11 11:56:42 jorgee dhclient[11554]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.94 on eth0 to 192.168.2.254 port 67 (xid=0x2894ec32)
Aug 11 11:56:42 jorgee dhclient[11554]: send_packet: Network is unreachable
Aug 11 11:56:42 jorgee dhclient[11554]: send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address.
Aug 11 11:56:42 jorgee dhclient[11554]: dhclient.c:2386: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
```

Edit:

Bind9 config:

```
acl lan {
    127.0.0.0/8;
    192.168.0.0/16;
};

view "lan-dmz" {
        match-clients { key lan-dmz; !key wan; lan; };
        server 192.168.1.24 { keys lan-dmz; };
        allow-recursion {lan; };
        recursion yes;
        zone "aaaa.edu.ar" {
        type master;
        file "/var/cache/bind/aaaa.edu.ar.lan-dmz";
};
        zone "aaaa.local" IN {
        type forward;
        forwarders { 192.168.1.123; 192.168.1.124;};
        };

};
view "wan" {
        match-clients { key wan; !key lan-dmz; !lan; any; };
        server 192.168.1.24 { keys wan; };
        recursion no;
        zone "aaaa.edu.ar" {
        type master;
    allow-transfer { 192.168.1.24; 170.210.44.2; 170.210.44.3; };
        allow-query { any; };
        also-notify { 192.168.1.24; 170.210.44.2; 170.210.44.3; };
        file "/var/cache/bind/aaaa.edu.ar.wan";


};
};
```

Comment: This isn't avahi-daemon, lemme know about your configurations and settings on your router. Are you using TKIP?

Comment: @FarazX are you talking about wireless security?

Comment: Yes I am, Exactly!

Comment: @FarazX I'm connected via lan cable, we do not have wireless here.

Comment: Alright, look, Withdrawing address record means IP address has been removed, but not via avahi-daemon. Tell us about your network state, topology, and etc.?

Comment: Lemme ask you some question for quicker conclusion if possible, does your DNS server have a `.local` domain?

Comment: @FarazX I have updated with the Bind config, I see a .local there but not sure if that is what u are looking

Comment: Great, thanks for update. So ... I think you need to read this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04), and also this official help from [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns-configuration.html).

Comment: Having the same problem. Looks like there is a confirmed bug in avahi (?) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/avahi/+bug/1586528

Answer (score 1):

It appears the setup script for avhi-autoipd is failing.  This results in the log likes like this one.

```
Aug 11 11:54:16 jorgee root: /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/avahi-autoipd returned non-zero exit status 1
```

This likely gets treated as a failed connection and causes DHCP to retry after a timeout.  It is likely the command `/usr/sbin/avahi-autoipd -k $interface` is failing.  Try running this command with the appropriate value for `$interface`.  You may need to reinstall or purge the `avahi-autoipd` package.